# Value in Auxiliary Constructor

Tags: scala

I understand that values/vars cannot be created in an auxiliary constructor.  So how does one utilize apply or some other technique to allow the following code to work?

Also its somewhat of a requirement to not hack it by moving the value creation to inside the `this()`, of course I realize this is a possibility.

```
class DistanceCalculator(context: GeoApiContext) {    

    def this() {
        val context = new GeoApiContext()
          .setApiKey("AIza...")
          .setConnectTimeout(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
          .setReadTimeout(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
          .setWriteTimeout(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)

        this(context)
    }
}
```

Gabor informed me values can come after calling this() but I am uncertain the following would be the right way.

```
class DistanceCalculator(var context: GeoApiContext) {

    def this() {

        this()

        this.context = new GeoApiContext()
          .setApiKey("AIza...")
          .setConnectTimeout(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
          .setReadTimeout(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
          .setWriteTimeout(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)

    }
}
```

Comment: In this case, should it not be: `this(new GeoApiContext()
          .setApiKey("AIza...")
          .setConnectTimeout(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
          .setReadTimeout(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
          .setWriteTimeout(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS))`? (`val`, `var` are allowed after calling `super` or `this` constructor.)

Comment: @GáborBakos You gave me an idea, updated the post.  The code you provided is what I am trying to avoid for readability's sake.  Wondering what you think.

Comment: In this case your first line in the aux constructor it should be: `this(null)`. It should work that way. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
object DistanceCalculator {
  def defaultContext = new GeoApiContext()
          .setApiKey("AIza...")
          .setConnectTimeout(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
          .setReadTimeout(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
          .setWriteTimeout(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
}
```

Here are two approaches:

```
class DistanceCalculator(context: GeoApiContext) {    
    def this() = this(DistanceCalculator.defaultContext)
}
```

or using a `var` for the main constructor and set the context later:

```
class DistanceCalculator(var context: GeoApiContext) {
    def this() {
        this(null)
        this.context = defaultContext
    }
}
```

Comment: I like the first approach very much.  Simple.  Elegant.

Comment: I added the singleton reference to get the first approach code to work.  Could also import the singleton to its companion class.